# Сохранение данных виджета после выгрузки из памяти

Tags: виджет, android-sdk, android

Здравствуйте!
Сильно не пинайте, я только учусь.

Имеется виджет для андроида, который парсит данные с сайта и выводит в виде списка.
Проблема заключается в том, что при выгрузке его из памяти (тяжелая задача, игра, когда система убивает все не слишком важное) пропадают и спарсенные данные из массивов, и ему снова требуется Интернет для их обновления или просто стоит пустой в случае его отсутствия.

Подскажите, как это возможно вылечить?

(Пока склоняюсь к SharedPreference или SQLite, но первый случай требует преобразование массива в сет и потом обратно, а второй - кучу лишнего кода. Как я понял, SavedInstanceState реагируют только на активити.)

**UPD**

Может кому пригодится код который я использую в виджете для сохранения массива в SharedPreferences. Это переработанная версия варианта найденного на забугорном СтакОверфлов.

```
public boolean saveArray(SharedPreferences pref, ArrayList<String> wSave)
  {
      SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit1 = pref.edit();
      mEdit1.clear();
      mEdit1.putInt("Status_size", wSave.size());

      for(int i=0;i<wSave.size();i++)  
      {
         mEdit1.remove("Status_" + i);
          mEdit1.putString("Status_" + i, wSave.get(i));  
          Log.d("Save to shared", wSave.get(i));
      }

      return mEdit1.commit();     
  }

  public ArrayList<String> loadArray(SharedPreferences pref)
  {   List<String> sKey = new ArrayList<String>();
      sKey.clear();
      int size = pref.getInt("Status_size", 0);

      for(int i=0;i<size;i++) 
      {
          sKey.add(pref.getString("Status_" + i, null));
          Log.d("Load string", sKey.get(i));
      }
      return (ArrayList<String>) sKey;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) В SavedInstanceState я бы не рекомендовал это пихать. Были случаи, когда на больших объёмах данных приложение просто переставло отвечать из-за этого.

2) SharedPreference... При больших объёмах данные будет о-о-о-очень тормозить. Даже при использовании sax парсеров.

3) SQLite. Да, кода многовато, надо написать (создание табличек, сами запросы и т.п.). Но, зато будет:

а) быстро работать;

б) удобно использовать.

**UPD:**
Для сохранения SharedPreferences в onUpdate/onDeleted у вас есть Context, с помощью которого можно сохранить данные:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String value = prefs.getString("key-string", null);
    if(value != null){
        // что-то делаем
    }
}
```

Так же можно и сохранить.

Comment: Объем очень маленький (максимум 15 записей), подскажите реализацию SavedInstanceState в виджете? Т.к. информации найти не могу в нете.

Comment: @Kvazio onSaveInstanceState только для Activity, насколько я знаю. Так что вам лучше SharedPreference использовать, если там записей действительно мало будет.

Comment: @Suvitruf Буду благодарен, если ткнете носом на пример реализации этого в виджете.

Comment: @Kvazio реализацию работы с SP? У вас в виджете есть метод onUpdate. У него есть Context в параметрах. С помощью него и сохраняйте. Обновил пост.